# How do I remove a passcode on a PS3?

Tags: ps3

I bought a used PS3 from GameStop and I did the factory reset but every time I go to set a passcode on it, it still asks for my old one (which for obvious reasons I don't have)

Comment: Passcode for an account?

Comment: Not for an account, on the system. Like, go to Settings -> Security Settings -> Change Password. Then it says I have to enter my current password (4 digit number code)

Comment: It sounds like talking to the GameStop you got the console from would be your best bet to get this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The [PlayStation website](https://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/security.html) states that if the system is reset to factory defaults the PIN is set to [0000]

```
Change Password
Change the password required to adjust system settings. A password is required in the following cases:

When playing content with parental control restrictions
When changing the system's parental control level or Internet Browser Start Control setting
When starting the browser with the Internet Browser Start Control setting set to [On].
When changing the current password
Make a note of your new password. The password is set to [0000] in the default settings.

Hint
If you select  (Settings) >  (System Settings) > [Restore Default Settings], you can reset the password to [0000]. Note that all other settings will also be restored to their default values.
```